# Effect of relative strength on nature of solution

Tags: acid-base, reaction-mechanism

If a solution has equal no. of gram equivalents of a week acid (say acetic acid) and a strong base say NaOH , will the soltution be neutral or the relative strength has some role making solution slightly basic?

Comment: Note that the concept of _gram equivalents_ was used in the 19th century. In general chemistry, it has been superseded by the concept of molar mass.

Comment: @Loong Wish you could get that point across to our education system...

Answer (score 1):

The conjugate base of a weak acid is basic, whereas the conjugate acid of a strong base is not acidic. When a weak acid and strong base neutralize each other, the basicity of the conjugate base formed makes the solution basic.